# C# UWP 'BlankPage1' does not contain a definition for 'Button2_Click'

Tags: c#, uwp

Totally new to C# and UWP so this has been a tough few days :(

I'm moving from a VB.NET background.

Ok so starting out with a relatively simple snippet from Microsoft Example Docs pasted in to a button.

```
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = 
Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (folder != null)
{
    // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder
    // (including other sub-folder contents)
    Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.
    FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
    this.textBlock.Text = "Picked folder: " + folder.Name;
}
else
{
    this.textBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
}
```

After accepting the changes to that the method is converted to Async, I get the message "'BlankPage1' does not contain a definition for 'Button2_Click' and no extension method 'Button2_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'BlankPage1' could be found" in the BlankPage1.g.cs file.

```
case 2: // BlankPage1.xaml line 13
                {
                    this.Button2 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)this.Button2).Click += this.Button2_Click;
                }
                break;
```

The error is highlighted under the "this.Button2._Click;" text.

I assumed that this happened because the method name changed but this didn't fix it.

I admit this is going to be a noob error but I really can't figure this out.

Thanks all,

Comment: Check if this.Button2_Click exists.. if it does, the signature should by private async void Button2_Click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `this.Button2_Click` exists.. if it does, the signature should be `private async void Button2_Click`

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I got the wrong end of the stick and was trying to change code in the g.cs file. After the auto async correction VS performed, it changed the method name and added "Async" after the name.